# Trying to pass a string between C# classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm trying to pass a string between C# classes by using a session. I have a class called `Profile` and it has a search box. I have another class called `SearchResults` that is supposed to search my database for whatever was entered in the search box.

Upon clicking on the search button, this method in the `Profile` class is called:

```
 protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("~/SearchResults.aspx");
     String searchedItem = txt_search.Text;
     Session["search"] = searchedItem;
 }
```

and here is the `Page_Load` method in the `SearchResults` page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string searchedItem = (string)(Session["search"]);

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand SearchGames = new SqlCommand("SearchGames", conn);
    SearchGames.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SearchGames.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@game_name", searchedItem));

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = SearchGames.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

}
```

I'm getting an error saying that my

> SearchGames procedure needs an @game_name parameter which wasn't
>   supplied

, however it's clear that I've passed that parameter, which leads me think that there's something wrong with `SearchItem` (or how I'm passing the string between the two classes.

Comment: Have you debugged it to see if `searchedItem` has any value?

Comment: Remove the `@` from the `SqlParameter` name.

Comment: Re-check the version of your `SearchGames` SP and make sure you are hitting the correct DB. @Izzy - Does that really make any difference? It will never throw that error if `searchedItem` doesn't has any value.

Comment: Rather than passing the value via the session, why not add it as a parameter to the `Response.Redirect` URL?

Comment: @davidArno How can I do that?

Comment: @Amitkumarghos That's incorrect. Parameters need an '@'. And Rahul, I checked, everything should be working fine.

Comment: @Swailem95: `Response.Redirect("~/SearchResults.aspx?search=" + txt_search.Text);`. And in `SearchResults.aspx`: `string search = Request.QueryString["search"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redirect before setting the session, I think you should redirect after setting session:

```
String searchedItem = txt_search.Text;
Session["search"] = searchedItem;
Response.Redirect("~/SearchResults.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to pass the parameter via the session, inject it into the redirect:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect($"~/SearchResults.aspx?search={txt_search.Text}");
}
```

or, if not using C# 6,

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/SearchResults.aspx?search=" + txt_search.Text);
}
```

Then within `Page_Load`, change it to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchedItem = Request.QueryString["search"];
    ...
```

That way, you avoid passing values through global variables, which will make the code more robust and make testing easier.